# switching users in sshpass causes a an unexpected error from the server

Tags: ssh, sshpass

I am using the following line:

`sshpass -p 'PASSWORD' ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@hostname "sudo su - diffUser 'cd ${HOME} && git clone <reponame>'"`

I get the following error:

[image: unexpected error]